# Why Realisic Fps Prefab guns becomes too big in the game play?

Tags: unity-game-engine, model

I am using Realistic Fps prefab kit in my game , the problem I am facing is in scene view guns look in normal size but when i play the game they become so big but scale transform remains the same , Is there any way i can limit guns to normal size

[image: In Game Scene]

[image: In play mode]

Comment: Does that asset have a forum? or simply ask the developer of it in its asset store page.

Comment: well the asset was hot asset on assetstore but now its deprecated by unity , almost every unity developer knows about it thats why i am asking on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

did you resize it on the editor? If there's any bone attached to the gun, you have to resize both bone and mesh together